# Need to pull a specific message using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am very new to spark. I am trying to pull the date and the error message from the following error log

> Nov 11 09:44:53 www httpd[1933]: [error] [client 10.2.23.89] (36)File name too long
>
> Nov 11 09:49:38 www httpd[2728]: [error] [client 10.2.23.128] (36)File name too long
>
> Nov 11 10:14:23 www httpd[4530]: [error] [client 10.2.23.243] (36)File name too long
>
> Nov 11 10:15:24 www httpd[4630]: [error] [client 10.2.23.42] (36)File name too long
>
> Nov 11 12:05:07 www httpd[12062]: [error] [client 10.2.23.148] (36)File name too long

This my script which I have used in scala shell

```
val inputfile = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/kirthi/errorlog.txt")

val elog = inputfile.map(line => (line.substring(0, 6),line.substring(65, 83)))

elog.collect()
```

This is the output am getting but it's not as expected. The message is not completely pulled in all the tuples. Since the length of each line of log varies.

```
 Array[(String, String)] = Array((Nov 11,File name too long), (Nov 11,)File name too lon), (Nov 11,)File name too lon), (Nov 11,File name too long), (Nov 11,6)File name too lo))
```

But I want the output as posted below

```
Array[(String, String)] = Array((Nov 11,File name too long), (Nov 11,File name too long), (Nov 11,File name too long), (Nov 11,File name too long), (Nov 11,File name too long))
```

If I increase the length of the substring, I am hitting with an array out of bounds expectation error.

Comment: This more of a regex question than a Spark question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious way to parse text would be using *Regular Expressions*, of course. In this case, assuming the structure of these log records is always something like:

```
<date: MMM dd HH:mm:ss> www httpd[<number>]: [<level>] [client <IP>] (<number>)<text>
```

You can use something like:

```
val regex = "(\\w+ \\d+) [0-9:]+ www httpd\\[\\d+\\]: \\[\\w+\\] \\[.+\\] \\(\\d+\\)(.+)$".r
```

which matches this structure and will capture the date part and the text at the end, for example using pattern matching:

```
val elog = inputfile.map { case regex(date, text) => (date, text) }
```

P.S. This isn't really a Spark question (you got the Spark part right, assuming you're OK with collecting all the data from the cluster to your driver application).

Comment: Thanks Tzach,It works fine. But could you please explain me if need to pull this ip [client 10.2.23.243] can I use the same regex as above and also please let me to how to map the same, what is need to use instead of (date,text). Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't really work that way (you shouldn't add new questions in comments...), read a bit about using regular expressions in Scala and you'll be able to figure it out: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex